# Axios route, undefined optional parameter

Tags: typescript, api, axios

So ultimately I want to pass in a value for an optional parameter but 'undefined' is getting interpeted as a string, and not behaving like I want. What am I missing here? By default the route should be /api/todo/get/ I know I can just leave off 'showAll' but want avoid an awkward if else. Thanks.

```
const getTodos = (showAll = undefined): Thunk<Promise<void>> => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(setTodos([]));
  return axios.get(`/api/todo/get/${showAll}`).then((res) => {
    dispatch(setTodos(res.data));
  });
};


router.get("/get/:includeCompleted?", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const includeCompleted = req.params.includeCompleted;
    console.log(req.params.includeCompleted);
    return database
        .raw<Todo[]>(
            `
        SELECT *
        FROM todo
        WHERE :includeCompleted = 1 OR completedDate IS NULL
    `,
            {includeCompleted: includeCompleted ? 1 : 0}
        )
        .then((data) => res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json(data));

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just test `showAll` for falsiness using short-circuit evaluation. If it's falsey, just use an empty string:

```js
return axios.get(`/api/todo/get/${showAll || ''}`)
```

**Edit:** As a commenter pointed out, short-circuit evaluation might be too aggressive if you want values like `0` or `false` to still be passed to the route. If that's the case, use the nullish coalescing operator:

```js
return axios.get(`/api/todo/get/${showAll ?? ''}`)
```

Comment: I recommend to use the `??` operator instead of `||`
Ref: https://mariusschulz.com/blog/nullish-coalescing-the-operator-in-typescript

Comment: Hmm, it could definitely work, but I'm wondering what falsey values we would want to consider valid?

Comment: I think maybe if `showAll` equals `0` you _might_ want that to be used rather than an empty string, but I'm not sure if that's a valid case

Comment: I updated the nullish coalescing option to the answer, thanks @KBeDev

Comment: It highly depends in the specific requirements of the endpoint. Since `showAll` is defined implicitly as `any` type, the use of `??` or `||` is a decision of the developer